# How to add text to flutter Analog Clock using canvas CustomPainter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-canvas, flutter-custompainter

I just learned about making Analog Clock with flutter CustomPainter, and I know to make every hour mark with `canvas.drawline(p1, p2, dashBrush)`.

this is my Analog clock hour mark code :

```dart
var outerCircleRadius = radius;
var innerCircleRadius = radius - 14;

for (double i = 0; i < 360; i += 90 / 3) {
   var x1 = centerX + outerCircleRadius * cos(i * pi / 180);
   var y1 = centerX + outerCircleRadius * sin(i * pi / 180);

   var x2 = centerX + innerCircleRadius * cos(i * pi / 180);
   var y2 = centerX + innerCircleRadius * sin(i * pi / 180);
   
   //Draw Hour line is hire
   canvas.drawLine(Offset(x1, y1), Offset(x2, y2), dashBrush);
      
}
```

How do I change from drawLine dashBrush to an hour number?

Comment: either use `Canvs.drawParagraph()` or `TextPainter`

Comment: check https://gist.github.com/pskink/bc6e9112b52a73df69a2315945758c42#file-rotated_labels-dart-L220 how it can be done with even rotated text